# Can Blogger API retrieve metrics such as pageviews?

Tags: google-blogger-api

Is there a way to get blogger blog metrics such as pageviews via the Blogger API? I've searched through the API docs, and it seems very limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is :)
Seems they developed it lately.

https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/pageViews/get